# Create matrix with diagonal element is matrix in r

Tags: r, matrix, sparse-matrix

I have a 2X2 matrix, for instance `A=matrix(1:4,2,2)`. With this matrix, I want to build matrix whose diagonal element is A like below. This example has just three A but I would like to make matrix with n diagonal element of matrix A

```
|A  0  0|
|0  A  0|
|0  0  A|
```

Comment: see Matrix package... `bdiag`: `bdiag(rep(list(A), 3))`

Comment: `n <- 3; nr <- nrow(A); ii <- vapply(1:n, function(x) row(A) + (x - 1L) * nr, integer(nr ^ 2)); \`[<-\`(matrix(0, nr * n, nr * n), cbind(c(ii), sort(ii)), rep(A, n))` will work for square matrices.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a recursive solution:

```
CreateDiag<-function(n){
 if (n==1) {
    return(A)
 } else{
    A_2<-CreateDiag(n-1)
    temp1<-cbind(A_2,matrix(0,nrow = nrow(A_2),ncol = ncol(A)))
    temp2<-rbind(temp1,cbind(matrix(0,nrow = nrow(A),ncol = ncol(A_2)),A))
    return(temp2)
 }
}
```

(`n` is the number of blocks you want)

Comment: Once I tried n=1600, I got this error message

Comment: Error: evaluation nested too deeply: infinite recursion / options(expressions=)?

Comment: do you know how to do it?

Comment: and, I executed options(expressions=10000), and I did again CreateDiag(1600). but it takes too much time. can you give any solution?

Answer (score 0):

```
> DiagonalMatrix <- function(n, x) `diag<-`(matrix(0, n, n), x)
> DiagonalMatrix(2, 10)
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]   10    0
[2,]    0   10
```